# NPM breaks after it has been upgraded in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, ubuntu-16.04

I need to create a docker container with node `v6.10.3`, but with the latest npm (currently `v5.4.1`) to use new npm features for local packages.

Such installation runs without any problem on my Mac, but when I try to create a docker image with such an installation, after updating npm, the npm tool gets broken and throws a bunch of errors about missing packages.

Here is the example of the Dockerfile, with which I can reproduce this issue (note that my real Dockerfile is more complex):

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN npm i -g npm
RUN npm i -g lerna
```

When the build process gets to the line `RUN npm i -g lerna` it throws a bunch of errors like:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:26:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Any other npm script would result in the same errors. Reinstalling all the packages on which npm depends, does not seem as a solution for me.

I have also tried to install node inside the container using `nvm`, but I got the same errors.

My docker version:

```
Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72
```

What's wrong with this Dockerfile and what am I missing?

Comment: Have exactly the same issue here, all of a sudden. Didn't change a thing to my Dockerfile nor package.json, but I can't deploy my project anymore. And since it is some kind of 5th level dependency (it's the same package that fails) good luck finding out who's responsible for causing this problem and providing a fix ...

Comment: @JorisMans, for now I'm satisfied with the workaround posted below (installed npm using yarn). Maybe it could be useful for you your environment as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this issue, using `yarn`.

It looks weird, but it works:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN npm i -g yarn
RUN npm uninstall npm -g
RUN yarn global add npm
RUN npm i -g lerna
```

**Still, it would be great if somebody can explain why the original solution did not work, and/or help find a better way to fix it.**

Comment: I don't know how you came up with this, but it also solves the problem on my side. FYI I am installing with a FROM node:7 Docker image.

Comment: You can just use the official [node images](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) which come with `yarn` already installed.